# Programmatically made checkboxes at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox

I am making an application in which I am making checkboxes programmatically. I have made the checkboxes and it is running in different versions of android from 2.3 to 4.4.

There are few problems which I am facing while running on several versions of android such as padding and spacing between checkboxes.

This is my checkbox code

```
   cbs[i] = new CheckBox(AddPoints.this);

                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams chkBoxParams = new     LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                150, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        cbs[i].setLayoutParams(chkBoxParams);

                        cbs[i].setText(namesplit[i]);
                        cbs[i].setId(x1);
                        cbs[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        cbs[i].setTextSize(12f);
                        cbs[i].setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox);
                        cbs[i].setPadding(35,5,25,5);
                        cbs[i].setTag(i + 1);
                        cbs[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(handleCheck(cbs[i]));
                        lLayout[j].addView(cbs[i]);
```

These are following images of the different versions of android showing checkboxes -

Device Name - 2.7" QVGA
Screen Size  -  240X320 pixels
Emulator version – 2.3.6 Google API

[image]

Device Name - Nexus S
Screen Size  -  480X800 pixels
Emulator version – 4.0 GoogleAPI

[image]

Device Name - Nexus S
Screen Size  -  480X800 pixels
Emulator version – 4.4 GoogleAPI

[image]

Device Name -  2.7"QVGA
Screen Size -  480X800 pixels
Emulator version – 2.3 Google API

[image]

Comment: maybe you should start thinking in dip instead of pixels?  `cbs[i].setPadding(35,5,25,5);`

Comment: how can I set padding in dip of checkbox.?

Comment: multiply your magic numbers per   screen density

Comment: What does that mean?...what sort of magic number are you talking abt?

Comment: `35 * screenDensitiy`, `5 * screenDensity` and so on.. pay attention to the float/int cast

Comment: for example: what can be screen density or you mean to say i have to define individually for all screen sizes..

Comment: no no screen density depends on the screen. Yon ca retrieve it through the resources

Comment: okay...how can i do it??..is there any code for it...if so..!! let me know.

Comment: please assist me with the code....!